# How do I set the default paste special in excel to paste only values

Tags: excel, default, paste

One of the cells in my excel is used as a user entry box... IF users paste something in this cell I want only the values to be pasted and not the format. Is there a way to set the default of paste option to paste only values?

Comment: While you cannot set Paste Values as the default Paste or Paste Special setting, you can quickly add Paste Values to the QAT. See my solution on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/840143/is-there-a-way-to-autofill-cells-in-excel-2013-with-keyboard-shortcuts/840169#840169) for details.

Comment: Due to a number of people using this excel, more common is using ctrl+v or right click paste... Though i have instructions in there to use the QAT to paste, I am sure users will tend to paste using the traditional paste

Comment: The best way is to create macro for that so you can assign CTRL+B for example. Tutorial: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/work-with-macros-in-excel-online-98784ad0-898c-43aa-a1da-4f0fb5014343

Answer (score 11):

I use a keyboard shortcut to past the values. If you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will past the values. (hit keys in sequence, don't hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.)

<kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> will open the paste special dialog box, <kbd>V</kbd> will select `Values` and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> will make it happen. This works well for anything copied from excel.

If you are copying something from outside excel, it will give you some different options for paste special, but <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> will get you there.

Another option, as @jeeped mentioned, is you can add a button to your quick access toolbar and then you can either click them, or use a keyboard shortcut for those. The items are numbered on the quick access toolbar. Assuming you have the default save, undo, and redo, adding paste values will allow you to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (or whatever number comes up when you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>) and select that action.

Comment: I may not be able to do this because this excel will be used my a number of users and I cannot instruct each one of them follow these.. While they are all basic excel users giving them so many instructions will lead to confusion...

Comment: Another option: (1) record macro to paste-as-value, (2) save macro to `personal.xls` (it's a special spreadsheet that starts up with Excel, (3) assign macro to execute on `Ctrl+V`. Only downside is you won't be able to undo after you execute this macro.

Comment: Due to the way excel records macros, you'll probably have to tweak the macro to get rid of the parts that select specific cells so you can keep it generic. I would suggest having a different keyboard shortcut if you so this, though `ctrl+shift+v` should be sufficient.

Comment: Brian, the way I do it is by pressing <Right click> (keyboard button), <V>. This saves you some key presses.

Comment: Alt-h-v-m for newer versions with the ribbon

Comment: Yes, you can also use Alt and navigate through the ribbon. Either way works fine, though for 2016, it's Alt, h, v, v for ribbon nav.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify you default paste, go to the option menu, in the advance parameters: there are options to [modify the print default parameters](http://blogs.technet.com/b/hub/archive/2010/11/04/adjusting-your-default-paste-options-in-office.aspx). **However**, it does not seems to work on excel.

As a workaround, you could try to create a new macro or edit an existing one, using office support [here](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Edit-a-macro-ed9e8c3d-58fd-47a1-83eb-bdee680376bb). I didn't try it myself, but with some research it might be possible, if you really need this modification.