# Excel VBA - PasteSpecial - Issues with formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on code to have it to where when you press ctrl + V it will automatically do paste values within it. I have tried a few different lines of code but none of them seem to work. Here is what I have right now.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
End Sub
```

It seems to partially work. The problem I'm having is when I paste something in Excel the Font & Font Size is the same as the original not like when you right click and select paste - Paste values which keeps the formatting of the page you are pasting to. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2545-excel-set-paste-values-as-default.html? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31789658/11683?

Comment: @GSerg So the Extend Office link, I attempted that code but it does the same thing. The worksheet I copy from has font as Calibri and size 9 and that is moved over to the sheet I use which has font of Cambria and size of 24. This is a worksheet that is shared with a lot of people and if we use the changing Office settings it won't work. Also the alt string of commands is something that people would forget is why we wanted to set up a macro that could do it.

Comment: This code paste values without one having to hit Ctrl+V... hitting Ctrl+V will just do a regular paste, which will of course  paste the format.

Comment: So how would I paste the values? It doesn't show up under my list of macros